# libvlc: EventHandler.MediaPlayerStopped Event in Android

Tags: android, event-handling, libvlc

In my `Android` application i have integrated `org.videolan.libvlc` for live video streaming. Everything is working fine.

But sometimes got `EventHandler.MediaPlayerStopped` event.

Why this event occurred?

Thank you.